# PHP add multiple JOIN method in function

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this function for fetch `catid` and `typeid` from MySQL database.

```
function _is_type_($id,$type){

    $db = mysqli_access::F("SELECT catid,typeid FROM " . CATSGROUP . " WHERE postid = ? AND typeid = ?", $id, $type);

    foreach($db as $row){
      $catsdata[] = $row;
    }
    return $catsdata;
}
```

catsgroup table:(insert for each post catid and typeid)

```
|id|  catsid  |  typeid  |  postid  |
```

I have ***another*** two table for cats name and type name like this :

cats name table:

```
|id|cat_name|
```

type table:

```
|id|type_name|
```

Now In action I need to show/print name of `catid` and `typeid` from another table. I know, I can add PHP `JOIN` method in my function but I don't know how do can I?!
How do generate my result (show name o cats and type) using `JOIN` method for my function?

Now

Comment: Please provide some data sample.

Comment: @RubahMalam: see my edit please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will require join in this case as you need to fetch data from two different tables with two different keys. Also, I am assuming that id column in name and type table has no relation.

Here, writing to separate query can give you quicker result than going for join.

```
select cat_name from name where id=$id;
select type_name from type where id=$type;
```

Comment: see my edit. I add postid in another table and name to other table. how do find postid with your method ?!!

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like an SQL question. Also, as codeSun said there is no relation between the tables.

I suggest you read up on databases/sql.

Still, to answer your question, your query should go something like this:

`$db = mysqli_access::F("S
SELECT catid,typeid,{your join table}.type_name
FROM " . CATSGROUP . "
INNER JOIN {your join table} ON {your join table}.{pk} = " . CATSGROUP . ".{fk}
WHERE postid = ? AND typeid = ?", $id, $type);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and give some feedback.

```
select a.catid,a.typeid,b.cat_name,c.type_name
from catsgroup a
inner join catsname b on b.id = a.catid
inner join type c on c.id = a.typeid
where a.postid = ''
and a.typeid = ''
```

Comment: see this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Comment: Yes, the number of parameters you bind (the number of params after the query) should match the number of '?' in the query itself.